# Редукция гласных в первой безударной позиции

Tags: фонетика

Готовлюсь к ЕГЭ по русскому. В справочнике для подготовки указано, что редукция гласных в I слабой позиции выглядит так-
I слабая позиция после твердых согласных:
-на месте ударного звука [а] после непарных твердых согласных [ж], [ш], [ц] звучит редуцированный гласный [^], ударных [э], [о], после ... звучит редуцированный гласный, который обозначается звуком [ыэ].
Вопрос:

1. Звук [^] как-то произносится? Или просто обозначается на письме? Как читается слово с этим звуком?
2. О каких ударных гласных идёт речь, если это редукция гласных в слабой позиции, т.е. безударных?

Comment: К сожалению, текст неясный (неполный), примеров нет. Да и вопросы непонятные. Носитель языка знает, как читается звук  [^]. Это, к примеру,  первый гласный в слове "трава".